# How to redirect to parent directory (don't delete rest of URL) when integer in url

Tags: laravel, nginx

I've got an URL like:

```
https://website.com/XXX/123/AA/BB/CC/DD
```

and if 123 is integer I would like it to redirect to:

```
https://website.com/XXX/AA/BB/CC/DD
```

How can I do that in nginx or Laravel?

Comment: If the integer component is the second path element, try: `rewrite ^(/[^/]+/)\d+/(.*)$ $1$2 redirect;`

Comment: is integer only in second part of url ? or it can appear anywhere?

Comment: Integer is only in second part, the XXX is static, but rest like AA,BB are changing and it can be more or less of them, for example only /AA/BB or /AA/BB/CC/DD/EE/FF

Answer (score 0):

On the Laravel side, one way is to create a route to match the url pattern and then redirect. You can use [regular expression constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) to ensure the first part is an integer.

```php
Route::get('xxx/{integer}/{a}/{b}/{c}/{d}', function ($integer, $a, $b, $c, $d) {
    return redirect("/xxx/$a/$b/$c/$d");
})->where(['integer' => '[0-9]+']);
```